# Calling a .bat/.ps file from within a lisp file

Tags: batch-file, common-lisp, sbcl, ccl

How do we call a .bat file or powershell file from a lisp file in SBCL or CCL? We need to do this because the batch file calls gprolog commands with some arguments.

Note: LispWorks has something like below:

```
 (system:call-system-showing-output "runprolog 'KeyboardDisplay'")
```

where runprolog.bat is the file called with argument 'KeyboardDisplay'

If SBCL or CCL has no such command, can you suggest any other lisp compilers which will help with this task?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Running-external-programs.

Comment: and http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter9.html#Running-Other-Programs-as-Subprocesses.

Comment: Since it appears that the answer to this question can be found readily with a Google search in the documentation of the lisp implementations mentioned, I think this question is off-topic, as per [What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437)

Comment: I agree :). Sorry about that